# Any bibliography style file for Springer Edited Volumes?

Tags: bibtex

I am working contributed Chapters for an upcoming Springer book.. The online link

```
 https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/your-publication-journey/manuscript-preparation#toc-49271
```

does not provide any bibliography style for formatting the References. I like to use a *.bib file, enter my bibliography entries, and run BibTeX to generate References which is very convenient. The latex template has given me some sample format like this..
Any help on how to use a *.bib to generate the same is highly thanked!!

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99.}%

\bibitem{science-contrib} Broy, M.: Software engineering --- from auxiliary to key technologies. In: Broy, M., Dener, E. (eds.) Software Pioneers, pp. 10-13. Springer, Heidelberg (2002)
%
% Online Document
\bibitem{science-online} Dod, J.: Effective substances. In: The Dictionary of Substances and Their Effects. Royal Society of Chemistry (1999) Available via DIALOG. \\
\url{http://www.rsc.org/dose/title of subordinate document. Cited 15 Jan 1999}
%
% Monograph
\bibitem{science-mono} Geddes, K.O., Czapor, S.R., Labahn, G.: Algorithms for Computer Algebra. Kluwer, Boston (1992)
%
% Journal article
\bibitem{science-journal} Hamburger, C.: Quasimonotonicity, regularity and duality for nonlinear systems of partial differential equations. Ann. Mat. Pura. Appl. \textbf{169}, 321--354 (1995)

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Rather than search around for an exiting bibliography style file that meets all of your formatting needs, you may want to run the `makebst` utility that's part of the [custom-bib](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) package. (The `custom-bib` package was authored by the same person who wrote the well-known `natbib` citation management package.) Open a command window and type `latex makebst` to start the process; you'll step through a series of multiple-choice questions, with the default choice/answer clearly stated each time. The result will be bespoke bst file.